# SDL and GLFW only report one key (repeat) per poll even if multiple keys are held down at the same time

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2, glfw

```
SDL_Event event;
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
    if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN || event.type == SDL_KEYUP){
         //...
    }
}
```

and

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{

}
```

For example I press `W` and `S` at the same time, both libraries report that `W` and `S` have been pressed.

But if I continue to hold `W` and `S`, only one key will be reported as if the other isn't held down at all.

Also if I hold down `W` and `S` and only `S` is reported and I press another key for example `Q` both libraries won't report that any key is currently held down at all.

It seems that the keystate `repeated` for both libraries is pretty much useless.

Is this standard behavior or could it be that it just happens on my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SDL_GetKeyboardState`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) when handling the `SDL_KEYUP` and `SDL_KEYDOWN` events to check for the state of more than a single key at a time. The keyboard state holds the current state of all the keys. The [`SDL_GetModState`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetModState) call should be used for the modifer keys like Ctrl or Shift.

Quick example:

```
static void keyboard_handler()
{
    int n, count = 0;
    char buf[80];
    const uint8_t *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(&count);
    buf[0] = 0;
    if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) strcat(buf, "right ");
    if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) strcat(buf, "left ");
    if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]) strcat(buf, "up ");
    if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN]) strcat(buf, "down ");
    if (buf[0] != 0)
        printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Running this in response to the `SDL_KEYUP` and `SDL_KEYDOWN` events I get multiple words printed when holding down more that 1 arrow key at a time. eg:

```
left
right left
left up down
```